# Create separate window from Console Application

Tags: c#, multithreading, console-application, multi-window

I'm having a bit of a trouble trying to create a multi window'ed console application.  Currently, my application's main console window is used to collect user input and display output.

Much of this output comes from a separate thread, as live data comes in. I was wondering if there is a way  for me to separate my application into two windows, where the second window was either a console window or even any other kind of window that could display the text of the incoming strings... In particular, the main console window would be where the user input commands etc, and the second window displayed what the system was currently working on.  This second window could be entirely readonly.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  I would post code, but I don't really have anything relevant (that I can think of) to post....

Comment: High time to start playing with Winforms or WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be hard to do.

Here is answer for similar question: [Can you have multiple .net Consoles (as in Console.Writeline)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671163/can-you-have-multiple-net-consoles-as-in-console-writeline)

If you really want to do it, you can find logic here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/MultipleConsoles.aspx

Maby better approach will be to start another process (console app) and communicate between them thru IPC ( Interprocess communication ) - like named pipes .

More about IPC you can find: http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/01/wcf-comm-options

Comment: I guess what I'm wondering though, is if I can do this with the second window *not* being a console, and if there is another option (ie some sort of WPF window that reads the data etc..)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easier to just pop-up a Windows Form with a TextBox containing the data you wish to show. You can simply start a new thread and call Form.ShowDialog() to get the form to show.

Comment: If I start a new thread though, does that require another CPU... (This may expose my ignorance...).  I currently am already running a BackgroundWorker, so would that conflict with trying to run another thread?