# Open console from C# DLL and print output using it

Tags: c#, logging, dll, console, dllimport

There is a C# DLL project. It has one class and one public method Print().
Is there any possible way to open console from this DLL in order to display text? DLL is used by 3rd party program.

```
public class Logger // dll
{
    public void Print()
    {
        // Open Console
        // Standard output to console
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the right answer is no : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671163/can-you-have-multiple-net-consoles-as-in-console-writeline You can put your "second console" to a new exe, and start it from main console using "Process.Start"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found simple and straightforward solution [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.allocconsole). Console is allocated using `AllocConsole()` method invoked from **kernel32**:

**Import:**

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
static extern bool AllocConsole();
```

**Call:**

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    //... magic happens here
    AllocConsole();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    //... continue magic
}
```